# Flutter Checkbox not changing/updating/working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to learn checkboxes in Flutter.

The problem is, when I want to use checkboxes in Scaffold(body:) it is working. But I want to use it in different places like an item in ListView.

```
return Center(
    child: Checkbox(
  value: testValue,
  onChanged: (bool value) {
    setState() {
      testValue = value;
    }
  },
));
```

But it is not working, updating and changing anything.

Edit: I solved my problem with putting checkbox in a StatefulBuilder. Thanks to @cristianbregant

```
 return StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
  return Center(
    child: CheckboxListTile(
      title: const Text('Animate Slowly'),
      value: _valueCheck,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _valueCheck = value;
        });
      },
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty),
    ),
  );
});
```

Comment: In a ListView you have to rebuild all the list to see your changes

Comment: By not working, do you mean you receive an error in your console? If so, could you add it to your question

Comment: did you mean setState()? @Caffo17

Comment: No, just nothing happens checkbox not updating itself in ui @Nolence

Comment: @developer.alp i explain better what i mean. If you want to have a list of checkboxes, you have to track all the boolean value of thats. You can do it having a List<bool>. At the initial state that list is full of false. In the build of the ListView you have the index of the single element of the list. When you click on a checkbox you have to call setState((){ _list[index] = !oldValue }). This let you to rebuild the list with the new value. If you need I can post an example below.

Comment: Thank you so much I understood your point of view. I solved problem with putting it in StatefulBuilder.

Comment: @Caffo17 Can you show me a example with list of checkboxes

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try these maybe:

```
return Center(
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    title: const Text('Animate Slowly'),
    value: _valueCheck,
    onChanged: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
       _valueCheck = value;
      });
    },
    secondary: const Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty),
  ),
);
```

and remember that if you are using it in a dialog or `bottomsheet` you need to wrap the Checkbox Widget in a Stateful builder because the state does not update.

Comment: thank you so much! i tried it with StatefulBuilder and now it works.At first I thought there was no need to use StatefulBuilder if we put widget in a StatefulWidget

Comment: You are welcome! maybe consider set my answer as the one! :D

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks man! but why do we need stateful builder though?

Comment: Wrapping the checkbox inside a `StatefulBuilder()` saved me I was going crazy!! But can you explain why this behavior happens?

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes require you have a `Scaffold` or `Material` as their parent. Without either of these, you get this helpful error message:

```sh
The following assertion was thrown building Checkbox(dirty, state: _CheckboxState#1163b):
No Material widget found.

Checkbox widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material.
In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
```

Once you have a material ancestor, you can place the ListView as it's child and it should show fine:

```dart
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  var _foo = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Toggle Foo'),
              Checkbox(
                value: _foo,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() => _foo = value);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your detailed answer. However at top of my widgets I have a Scaffold widget. In short it was just like this Scaffold->body:Column->Container->CheckBox . But I solved my problem with StatefulBuilder. Also I hope StatefulBuilder will not be issue for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you will have to use both `initState` and `dispose`.

See my code example below:

```
class SettingsOrder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsOrderState createState() => _SettingsOrderState();
}

class _SettingsOrderState extends State<SettingsOrder> {

  List options = [];
  List<bool> newoptions = [];
  int selectedoption;
  bool checkedstatus;
  bool initialcall;

Future getproductlist(selectedoption, checkedstatus, initialcall) async{

    List updatedlist = [];

    final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
    int itempos = 0;
    options.clear();

    if(initialcall == false){
      for(var item in arguments['options']){
        updatedlist.add({
          'checkbox' : newoptions[itempos]
        });
        itempos++;
      }
    } else {
      for(var item in arguments['options']){
        updatedlist.add({
          'checkbox' : checkedstatus
        });
        newoptions.add(false);
        itempos++;
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      options = updatedlist;
    });
    
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    getproductlist(0, false, true);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
           width: double.infinity,
           child: ListView.builder(
             primary: false,
             shrinkWrap: true,
             itemCount: options.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return Container(
                child: Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(
                    unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey
                  ),
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                    title: Text(options[index]['name']),
                    value: options[index]['checkbox'],
                    onChanged: (newvalue){
                      int indexposition = index;
                      newoptions.removeAt(indexposition);
                      newoptions.insert(indexposition, newvalue);
                      getproductlist(indexposition, newvalue, false);
                    },
                    activeColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 130, 214, 1),
                    checkColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
               );
              }
            ),
           ),
          ),
       );
}
```